# Regex in java to find pattern like ${...} from given string

Tags: java, regex

I am a noob to regex.

I have string like:-

```
String str = "sbs 01.00 sip ${dreamworks.values} print ${fwVer} to 
              used ${lang} en given ${model}  in ${region}";
```

and
i have to extract all patterns matched with this type ${....}

Like:-  for given str result should be

```
${dreamworks.values} 
${fwVer}   
${lang}
${model}
${region}
```

further if it finds any duplicates then gives only one .
 for ex:-

```
String feed = "sip ${dreamworks.values} print ${fwVer} to ${fwVer} used
                ${lang} en ${lang}given ${model}  in ${region}"
```

result should be:-

```
 ${dreamworks.values}  
 ${fwVer}   
 ${lang}
 ${model}
 ${region}
```

only

this is my answer:-

```
PLACEHOLDER_PATTERN = "\\$\\{\\w+\\}";
```

but this one not giving the correct result.
it gives only

```
${fwVer}
${lang}
${model}
${region}
```

So please suggest me correct regex.

Comment: because "dreamworks.values" contains a . in it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not considering the `.` in between the word. `\\w` does not include the `dot(.)`.

You need to change your pattern to: -

```
PLACEHOLDER_PATTERN = "\\$\\{.+?\\}";
```

`dot(.)` matches everything, and that is what you want right?

Also, I have used here `reluctant` quantifier - `.+?` so that it only matches the first `}` after `{`, since if you use a greedy quantifier `(.+)`, `dot(.)` will also match the `}` in the way till it finds the last `}`.

---

**UPDATE: -**

To get just the unique values, you can use this pattern: -

```
"(\\$\\{[^}]+\\})(?!.*?\\1)"
```

It will match only those pattern, which is not followed by the string containing the same pattern.

**NOTE: -** Here, I have used `[^}]`, in place of `.+?`. It will match any character except `}`. So, now in this case, you don't need a `reluctant` quantifier.

`\1` is used for `backreferencing`, but we need to escape it with a backslash, and hence `\\1`, and `(?!...)` is used for `negative look ahead`.

Comment: What is this `String feed`? Can you explain a little more?

Comment: String feed = "sip ${dreamworks.values} print ${fwVer} to ${fwVer} used ${lang} en ${lang}given ${model}  in ${region}";   Please see the other case for duplicate string feed in given example.

Comment: You can add all your matched string to a `Set<String>`. It will automatically remove duplicates for you.

Comment: @user1808653.. You can try the updated pattern. It will give you unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Thats is, because the `.` is not included in `\w`. You need to create your own [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) then and add it there.

```
PLACEHOLDER_PATTERN = "\\$\\{[\\w.]+\\}";
```

See the pattern [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32o49).

However, this does not solve the problem, that you want no duplicates, but that is not a job for regular expressions.

If there could be more different characters between the curly brackets, then [Rohits answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13285846/626273) is better, that would match any characters till the closing bracket.

Comment: @jlordo, not within a character class. There a dot is only a dot and nothing special.

Comment: @stema - you are right, thanks for answering, learn new things on SO every day :)